# How can I scan a directory tree?

Tags: c++

I need to do a type of scanning, I've done the first part, the program will scan the directory informed and separate files from other directories, but I need to scan other directories also, look at my code:

```
void CompleteScan(const char root[], WCHAR *Extension,std::vector<FileStruct> &Return_Files,std::vector<WIN32_FIND_DATA> &Return_Directorys){
std::vector<FileStruct> files;
std::vector<WIN32_FIND_DATA> dir;

Scan(root, Extension, files, dir);

if(dir.size() > 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < dir.size(); i++){
        /*          Here is directory by directory scan         */
    }
}
```

the command Scan return a Vector of FileStruct (Directory and WIN32_FIND_DATA) and a Vector of Directorys, but I need to scan all Directorys, Example:

"C:\" the program scan this and return all of directorys on "C:\", before I scan all directorys in this, but I don't know what I have to do to make it Scan all directorys on the "C:\" directorys, look at this list for example:

1. C:\    {OK}
2. C:\Files      {OK}
3. C:\Files\First File    {Can't}
4. C:\Files\First File\Second File      {Can't}

Answer (score 0):

You have to recursively call your `CompleteScan` function for every directory found.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion! Pardon if I've dropped any punctuation; I don't have a Windows box to compile/test on.

```
/**
 * @brief Accumulates the files and directories under the given root directory
 * into the output vectors allfiles and alldirs that you provide.
**/
void CompleteScan(const char root[],
                  WCHAR *Extension,
                  std::vector<FileStruct> &allfiles,
                  std::vector<WIN32_FIND_DATA> &alldirs)
{
    std::vector<WIN32_FIND_DATA> subdirs;

    // Assuming your Scan function does what needs to be done with the allfiles
    // vector. If not, more code needed somewhere here to handle that.
    Scan(root, Extension, allfiles, subdirs);

    if(dir.size() > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < dir.size(); i++){
            // Visit this directory
            alldirs.push_back(dir);
            // Visit all descendant directories
            CompleteScan(dir.cFileName, Extension, allfiles, alldirs);
        }
    }
}
```